Google Android billing : Doing purchase on internal test getting error
Bug Description
Summary:
The app functions normally for testers who have been granted permissions, but for other users, a popup error appears stating: "Error: This item you were attempting to purchase could not be found."
Steps to Reproduce:
Setup the app according to the provided instructions.
Upload the app to internal testing.
Test the app with users who do not have granted permissions.
I'm review on production but the app name always mark as unreviewed.
Expected Result:
The app should function normally for all users.
Actual Result:
The app shows a popup error for users without permissions: "Error: This item you were attempting to purchase could not be found.". Billing Response code = 4 ITEM_UNAVAILABLE
Additional Information:
The issue does not occur for testers who have been granted permissions.
The problem persists only for other users.
The app should function normally for all users.

Can we please get a [mcve] with detailed steps what you did, not just what tutorial you tried to follow?
